# Convert multipage TIFF to PNG error

Tags: python, python-3.x, converters, python-imaging-library

I try to convert some multi-page tiff file to png and its works in 90% but there are some tiff file which give an error when I want to save as png.

What I try:

```
for page, frame in enumerate(ImageSequence.Iterator(tif_image), start=1):
    temp_file = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(),
                             next(tempfile._get_candidate_names()) + '.png')
    frame.thumbnail(frame.size)
    frame.save(temp_file, optimize=True)
```

And I get this error:

```
python3.5/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 418, in _getdecoder
return decoder(mode, *args + extra)
TypeError: function takes exactly 5 arguments (6 given)
```

and I print out the decoder, mode, *args + extra and I get this:

```
<built-in function tiff_lzw_decoder> RGB RGB 1
<built-in function zip_decoder> RGB RGB
E<built-in function libtiff_decoder> 1 1;I group4 5 1843988 1
```

Most of the time PIL use :

```
<built-in function tiff_lzw_decoder> RGB RGB 1
<built-in function zip_decoder> RGB RGB
```

decoders but with few tiff file use this `<built-in function libtiff_decoder> 1 1;I group4 5 1843988 1` decoder and I get the error.

Anyone know what should I do or give another way to convert multipage tiff files to pngs?

Comment: It could be that the TIFF decoder in the PIL doesn't handle multi-page TIFFs or an error in your `ImageSequence.Iterator`—and if it's the latter, it's impossible to tell from the little code in your question and a sample muli-page TIFF file.

Comment: @martineau its worked with many multipage tiff files, but there is some files which doesnt. I think the problem is when PIL use the libtiff_decoder when I want to save it

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that an [`ImageSequence`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/reference/ImageSequence.html) was a PIL class. Regardless, it sounds like it was designed for `.gif` and `.fli` (FLIC) type animation files, not TIFFs. If it _was_ then it could very well be a bug or deficiency in `PIL`. For anyone to here to really be able to help you, we still need at least a copy of one of the multi-page TIFF files that is failing so we can reproduce the problem (or provide you with a workaround). It would also be nice to a copy of an image file that works.

Comment: @martineau  `VERSION = '1.1.7'  # PIL version ` and `PILLOW_VERSION = '4.1.1'  # Pillow`  and `Python 3.5.3` what I use and  Its hard to share this tiff file because its a scanned invoices and its not so public :/

Comment: You should get the latest version of the `pillow` fork and try that. It sounds like a bug (which you should report if it's still in the latest version `4.2.1`). I say this because it [looks to me](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/reference/plugins.html#PIL.TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile) like it should support multi-page TIFF.

Comment: P.S. As for the sample file(s), if they contain sensitive information, then you'll need to remove it by editing the file—the `pillow` developers are likely to want one, too, because they may not have the ability to make one of their own. Since you say it sometimes works, another possibility is that the software _creating_ the TIFFs has a bug and occasionally makes a bad file (multi-page TIFFs not very common).